# JavaScript Time Exception Message

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a script that displays the amount of time until a period ends or starts in my school. One of the data sets in the array needs to be excluded from being counted as a period.

```
{ start: minutes(11, 20), end: minutes(11, 46) },
```

I want to exclude this data because its not a full fledged period, its lunch, and im not sure how I should go about doing it. Any ideas? Also the message would need to be changed to the user instead of.

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "There are " + timeLeft + " minutes left until period " + (i+1) + " is over."
```

Any ideas?

```css
body, html { 
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #a00000;
    margin: 0; /* remove default margins added by browsers */
}
.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   height: 100%;
}
#result {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color:black;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin:auto;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.lunch {
    width: 95px;
    background-color: #a00000;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Marking Period Countdow</title>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body onload="myFunction(myTime, periods);">
        <script>
            //Get current date & midnight
            var now = new Date();
            var midnight = new Date();
            midnight.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            //Get number of minutes that passed since midnight:
            var myTime = Math.floor((now.getTime() - midnight.getTime()) / 60000);
            //For Testing Purposes.
           // console.log(myTime + ' minutes passed since midnight.');

            function minutes(hour, min) {
                return hour * 60 + min;
            }

            //All the periods throughout my school day.
            var periods = [
                { start: minutes( 7, 45), end: minutes( 8, 34) },
                { start: minutes( 8, 38), end: minutes( 9, 30) },
                { start: minutes( 9, 34), end: minutes(10, 23) },
                { start: minutes(10, 27), end: minutes(11, 16) },
                { start: minutes(11, 20), end: minutes(12, 09) },
                { start: minutes(12, 12), end: minutes(12, 38) },
                { start: minutes(12, 42), end: minutes(13, 31) },
                { start: minutes(13, 35), end: minutes(14, 25) },
            ];

            function myFunction(myTime, periods) {
                periods.every(function (period, i) {
                    if (myTime < period.start) {
                        if (i == 0) {
                            console.log('School has not started yet');
                            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "School has not started yet";

                        } else {
                            var timeLeft = period.start - myTime;
                            console.log("There are " + timeLeft + " minutes left until period " + (i+1) + " starts.");
                            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "There are " + timeLeft + " minutes left until period " + (i+1) + " starts.";
                        }
                    } else if (myTime < period.end) {
                        var timeLeft = period.end - myTime;
                            console.log("There are " + timeLeft + " minutes left until period " + (i+1) + " is over.");
                            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "There are " + timeLeft + " minutes left until period " + (i+1) + " is over.";
                    } else if (i == periods.length - 1) {
                            console.log('School has finished for today');
                            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "School has finished for today";
                    } else {
                        return true; // keep looking for the right period
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="result"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Can you add another property to that data element, `isLunch = true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it more functional, you can create functions for your messages and then let the periods themselves define which messages they should display. Like the following.

```js
//Get current date & midnight
var now = new Date();
var midnight = new Date();
midnight.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
//Get number of minutes that passed since midnight:
var myTime = Math.floor((now.getTime() - midnight.getTime()) / 60000);

function minutes(hour, min) {
  return hour * 60 + min;
}

function defaultMessage(minutes, i) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "There are " + minutes + " minutes left until period " + (i + 1) + " is over.";
};

function lunchMessage(minutes, i) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Lunch will end in " + minutes + " minutes";
};

//All the periods throughout my school day.
var periods = [{
  start: minutes(7, 45),
  end: minutes(8, 34),
  message: defaultMessage
}, {
  start: minutes(8, 38),
  end: minutes(9, 30),
  message: defaultMessage
}, {
  start: minutes(9, 34),
  end: minutes(10, 23),
  message: defaultMessage
}, {
  start: minutes(10, 27),
  end: minutes(11, 16),
  message: defaultMessage
}, {
  start: minutes(11, 20),
  end: minutes(12, 09),
  message: defaultMessage
}, {
  start: minutes(12, 12),
  end: minutes(12, 38),
  message: lunchMessage
}, {
  start: minutes(12, 42),
  end: minutes(13, 31),
  message: defaultMessage
}, {
  start: minutes(13, 35),
  end: minutes(14, 25),
  message: defaultMessage
}, ];

function myFunction(myTime, periods) {
  periods.every(function(period, i) {
    if (myTime < period.start) {
      if (i == 0) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "School has not started yet";
      } else {
        var timeLeft = period.start - myTime;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "There are " + timeLeft + " minutes left until period " + (i+1) + " starts.";
      }
    } else if (myTime < period.end) {
      var timeLeft = period.end - myTime;
      period.message(timeLeft, i);
    } else if (i == periods.length - 1) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "School has finished for today";
    } else {
      return true; // keep looking for the right period
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #a00000;
  margin: 0;
  /* remove default margins added by browsers */
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
#result {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.lunch {
  width: 95px;
  background-color: #a00000;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction(myTime, periods);">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="result"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only *image* how many students will be wanting to know how much time they have left ;)

What I believe you're looking for with regards to the exclusion is:

```
if (myTime > periods[4].start && myTime < periods[4].end) {
    console.log('Lunch period');
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Lunch period";
}
```

Place that just before `if (myTime < period.start)`, and turn that line to an `else if`.

Not sure where your lunch break is from your array structure, but replace 4 with the break :)